# List of Swift Data Types

Tags: swift, types

I have a list of Swift Data Types, and I want to know if I missed any.

Here is my list:

```
Int
Double
Bool
String
Character
Optional
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can find a list of built-in swift data types here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_data_types.htm

Comment: The list would be infinite if you count all the _possible_ types, since you can make your own types, and would be _very_ long even if you only count the built-in nominal types... I wonder the usefulness of such a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely, completely wrong. The five categories of types are:

```
Class
Struct
Enum
Tuple
Closure
```

Int, Double, Bool, String and Character are structs, and Optional is an Enum. But if these are the ones you count as type, then each of the five type categories can contain an infinite number of types.

You got a link to a tutorial site that supposedly listed all built-in types. None of these types are built into the language. Many are built into the Swift library. There is syntactic sugar for "Optional" built into the language, but in reality the various "Optional" types are just Enums with two cases "none" and "some".

Comment: I never said categories...

Comment: You didn't. Which means you don't understand yet what types are. Is (Int, Int) a type? Yes, it is a tuple. Is (Int, Int) -> Double a type? Yes, it's a closure type.